# Java JSP show Image Icon from Controller in JSP

Tags: java, image, jsp, blob, jstl

I am trying to show the image that I have took from my database, but when the page opens it doesn't show the image. I have taken the image from the database which is saved as a blob, turned into byte[] and then turned it into an image icon. Then sending it to the jsp via model.addAttribute.
Here is the code where I am getting the blob and converting:
This is my controller method

```
if(post.getImage() != null) {
        Blob blob = post.getImage();
        ImageIcon ii=new ImageIcon(blob.getBytes(1, (int) blob.length()),"description");
        System.out.println("shalom " + ii);
        model.addAttribute("img", ii);
    }
```

And this is where I am trying to use the image

```
<img src="<c:out value="${img}"/>" width="100" height="100"></img>
```

If there's any ideas I would be very appreciative.
Cheers Jim :)

Comment: What actual output do you get in your page for that `img` tag? What does the `src` attribute of an `img` tag need to be?

Comment: I just get a white box (the css styling) I would upload a random picture say of a can of fanta and the white box is all I get. The src tag is being set by the model.addAttribute. So this would be the image icon of the image created.

Comment: I mean: what is the page source generated for that `img` tag?

Comment: `<img src="description" width="100" height="100"></img>` I am guessing this is the name of the file rather than the actual image.